# ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException even with cascade remove

Tags: symfony, doctrine, cascade

I'm trying to delete a OneToOne Entity relation.

A demand can only have one accepted purpose (proposition).
So, this is my demand entity:

```
class DemandeTransport extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=PropositionTransport::class, cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private ?PropositionTransport $propositionAcceptee;
}
```

It's a [unidirectional relationship](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional).
So when I delete a demand, it would delete the propositionAccepte too; but I got this error:

> There is a ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException for the Doctrine
> entity associated with "DemandeTransport".
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
> update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`transporteur`.`demande_transport`, CONSTRAINT `FK_1387DBFBF9EDB3E8`
> FOREIGN KEY (`proposition_acceptee_id`) REFERENCES
> `proposition_transport` (`id`))

Comment: Can you show the relationship in PropositionTransport class ?

Comment: No relationship on PropositionTransport because it's unidirectional

Comment: Did you try ti re-run make:migration ? I wonder if cascade is managed at database level...